# (AT&T Debian 32-bit OS) How to reverse a list of values into another variable in Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

So, the goal of this (school) assignment is to take an input file of 16 words of no longer than 16 characters in size (including a \n), reverse their order, and output them to a new file. The contents of the input file are below.

input.txt:

```
1. First.......
2. Second......
3. Third.......
4. Fourth......
5. Fifth.......
6. Sixth.......
7. Seventh.....
8. Eighth......
9. Ninth.......
10. Tenth......
11. Eleventh...
12. Twelfth....
13. Thirteenth.
14. Fourteenth.
15. Fifteenth..
16. Sixteenth..
```

So far, I've managed to take in the input file and assign it to a variable. I've verified this with temporary print statements (commented in my code below). But when I got to reverse this into an Output variable (before writing said variable to a new file), it doesn't work.

My current code below and the result I get after running it is below. I've been working at this for a good couple hours now and it is pretty frustrating how little info is out there about this particular syntax of Assembly, so any clear cut help would be appreciated. Take note -- I am a novice here so I may not understand assembly terms or concepts that might come across as basic. Bare with me please!

My code:

```
.section .data

InFileName:
      .asciz   "input.txt"
InFileHandle:
      .int     0
OutFileName:
      .asciz   "output.txt"
OutFileHandle:
      .int     0
Output:
      .fill    256

.section .bss

Input:
      .fill    256

.section .text
.globl _start

_start:
      movl     $5, %eax               # Open file
      movl     $InFileName, %ebx
      movl     $02, %ecx
      movl     $0777, %edx
      int      $0x80

      test     %eax, %eax             # Check for file error
      js       Error

      movl     %eax, InFileHandle     # Puts Input file handle into variable

      movl     $3, %eax               # Writes file to variable
      movl     InFileHandle, %ebx
      movl     $Input, %ecx
      movl     $InputLen, %edx
      int      $0x80

#     call     PrintVariable          # Temporary call for testing
      call     Reverse

PrintVariable:
      movl     $4, %eax
      movl     $1, %ebx
      int      $0x80
      ret

Error:
      call     ExitProg

Reverse:
      movl     $Input, %esi           # Move %esi to Input
      movl     $(Output+240), %edi    # Move %edi to end of Output
      cld                             # Clear direction flag
      movl     $16, %ecx              # Move input length to %ecx
      subl     $32, %edi              # Subtract twice input length from %edi
      rep      movsb                  # Repeat until %ecx is 0

      movl     $Output, %ecx          # Assign output for printing
      movl     $256, %edx

      call     PrintVariable          # Printing value for testing purposes

ExitProg:
      movl     $1, %eax
      movl     $0, %ebx
      int      $0x80
```

My output after running this code:

```
1. First.......
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong here, so any help would be much appreciated. After I solve this problem (reversing the inputted data into a new variable), I need to push that data into an output file. I'm sure I can figure that part out myself, but I won't say no to help there either.

Comment: Are they actually padded to 16-byte fixed-width elements like you showed with `...` padding?  That makes it pretty easy, no parsing necessary just the same as reversing an `int` array but with 16-byte `movdqa mem, %xmm0` loads/stores.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've no idea what that last sentence even means.

And yes, they are padded to a fixed length of 16.

Comment: [`movdqa`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movdqa:vmovdqa32:vmovdqa64) is a 16-byte load instruction, into an XMM register.  Or you could copy the 4 dwords separately, if you don't want to require SSE2 or SSE1 `movaps`, or just don't want to use the XMM registers at all.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think you may be referring to a different syntax. I've never heard of dword. As for SSE2/SSE1, I'm using a bare bones Debian 32-bit command line OS to write this using nano. That's all I have available/am allowed to use.

Comment: dword or double-word isn't part of AT&T *syntax* but that's not what I meant.  In Intel terminology, that's how you describe a 4-byte chunk of data.  Intel's and/or AMD's manuals are the best way to learn about the ISA, regardless of that asm syntax you're using.  The `l` suffix on `movl` means double-word, as opposed to `movw` meaning a 16-bit "word".  (That's not the "word size" of modern x86, BTW. Modern x86 doesn't really have a word size; different things are different sizes.) Anyway, SSE is available in 32-bit mode on all x86 CPUs since Pentium III in ~1998, but you don't have to use it.